# Need to format HTML to make proper table form

Tags: html

I am running script and getting output like this below, I need to make this HTML output into tabular form with Heading CE Pending Cases | Customer Updated Cases

- - CE Pending Cases
  - ========================
  - XXXXXXXX --> IMP Persistent Chat file share not working
- - Customer Updated Cases
  - ============================
  - XXXXXXXX --> Users not able to login to Jabber
  - XXXXXXXX --> Core Dump generated
  - XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX --> Error While creating sip trunk on CUCM
  - XXXXXXXX --> Prod-C4-Sub1 - CoreDumpFileFound events generated
  - XXXXXXXX --> Call Manager version 11.5.1.12900-21//Self signed cert showing expired

Comment: Aha. So, what you tried so far?

Comment: What do you want to display?

Answer (score 0):

Does below codes are what you want?

Two separate tables for the `CE Pending Cases` and `Customer Updated Cases`.

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <td colspan="2">CE Pending Cases</td>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>XXXXXXXX
        </td>
        <td>IMP Persistent Chat file share not working
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <td colspan="2">Customer Updated Cases</td>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>XXXXXXXX
        </td>
        <td>Users not able to login to Jabber</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>XXXXXXXX
        </td>
        <td>Core Dump generated</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        </td>
        <td>Error While creating sip trunk on CUCM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>XXXXXXXX
        </td>
        <td>Prod-C4-Sub1 - CoreDumpFileFound events generated</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>XXXXXXXX
        </td>
        <td>Call Manager version 11.5.1.12900-21//Self signed cert showing expired</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution Here !!!

```html
 <table style="width: 100%;" Border="1">
        <thead>
            <td colspan="2">CE Pending Cases</td>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>XXXXXXXX
            </td>
            <td>IMP Persistent Chat file share not working
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <br>
    <table style="width: 100%;" Border="1">
        <thead>
            <td colspan="2">Customer Updated Cases</td>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>XXXXXXXX
            </td>
            <td>Users not able to login to Jabber</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>XXXXXXXX
            </td>
            <td>Core Dump generated</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
            </td>
            <td>Error While creating sip trunk on CUCM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>XXXXXXXX
            </td>
            <td>Prod-C4-Sub1 - CoreDumpFileFound events generated</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>XXXXXXXX
            </td>
            <td>Call Manager version 11.5.1.12900-21//Self signed cert showing expired</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: I wanna do it in python automatically, instead updating manually